# MySQL 5.7 server has gone away, Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, debian, mysql-5.7

I'm super aware of all the questions with pretty much this exact same name on here, but none of their solutions seemed to be the answer to my problems.

The query I'm using isn't very big, and I definitely have my packet size settings all configured correctly (never had a problem like this and some of my queries are properly large, much larger than the query in question).

I'm using prepared statements to pass some data to a fulltext search, and only when I seem to use it this way, I get this error. If I take the text out and paste it in as part of the query instead of preparing it, it works fine.

Also, in the MySQL log I get a huge error that starts like this

> 21:31:08 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
>   This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
>   or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
>   or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
>   Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
>   As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
>   collection process might fail.

The query is this:

```
insert into`unpairedbillsuggestions`(`UnpairedBillSuggestionID`,
`ShippingBillID`,`InvoiceID`,`Score`,`DateTimeAdded`)
select`buuid`(),?,`InvoiceID`,`Score`,now()
from(select if(`invoices`.`InvoiceNumber`in(?,?,?),
5,0)`InvoiceNumberScore`,
if(`states`.`APO`=0,match(`shippingoptions`.`Company`,`shippingoptions`.`FullName`,`shippingoptions`.`AddressLine1`,
`shippingoptions`.`AddressLine2`)against(?),
match(`invoices`.`_APOCustomerAddress`)against(?))/
20`MatchScore`,
if(`invoices`.`_ShippingAccountNumber`=?,0.3,0)`ShippingAccountNumberScore`,-abs(datediff(date(`invoices`.`DateTimeShipped`),
ifnull(?,date(`invoices`.`DateTimeShipped`)-interval 14 day)))/7`DateScore`,
if(`invoices`.`_InvoiceTrackingNumberCount`=0,2,0)`InvoiceTrackingNumberCountScore`,`invoices`.`InvoiceID`,
`invoices`.`InvoiceNumber`,`invoices`.`DateTimeShipped`,`shippingoptions`.`FullName`,
`shippingoptions`.`Company`,`shippingoptions`.`AddressLine1`,`shippingoptions`.`AddressLine2`,
`shippingoptions`.`City`,`states`.`StateCode`,`countries`.`CountryCode3`,`shippingoptions`.`Zip`,
`invoices`.`_Total`,`invoices`.`_ShippingAccountNumber`,`companies`.`Name` `CompanyName`,`factories`.`Name` `Factory`,
`networks`.`Icon`,(select`InvoiceNumberScore`+`InvoiceTrackingNumberCountScore`+
`ShippingAccountNumberScore`+`MatchScore`+`DateScore`)`Score`
from`invoices`
left join`invoiceshippingoptions`using(`InvoiceID`)
left join`shippingoptions`
on`shippingoptions`.`ShippingOptionID`=`invoiceshippingoptions`.`ShippingOptionID`
left join`countries`on`countries`.`CountryID`=`shippingoptions`.`CountryID`
left join`states`on`states`.`StateID`=`shippingoptions`.`StateID`
join`companies`on`companies`.`CompanyID`=`invoices`.`CompanyID`
join`networks`on`networks`.`NetworkID`=`companies`.`NetworkID`
join`factories`on`factories`.`FactoryID`=`invoices`.`FactoryID`
where`invoices`.`InvoiceStatusID`<>'c9be156b-ffca-11e4-888d-3417ebdfde80'
having`Score`>0 
order by`Score`desc 
limit 5)`a`;
```

With the parameters being (all passed as strings):

1. '0a1c6452-4ec2-11e6-b570-12c139c58877'
2. '123456'
3. '789456123456'
4. ''
5. 'SOME COMPANY - SOME DUDE 117 W MASTER CHIEF LN, ORLANDO, FL 32816 USA'
6. 'SOME COMPANY - SOME DUDE 117 W MASTER CHIEF LN, ORLANDO, FL 32816 USA'
7. '456789123'
8. '2016-04-27'

Comment: *21:31:08 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;*  That's a hard crash of the entire MySQL server daemon.  Serious business, and almost by definition it can't be something you're doing wrong -- it's either an actual defect in MySQL, or defective hardware or previously corrupted data structures. `SELECT @@VERSION;` to determine the exact version you are running.  It could be already fixed in a newer minor version or there may be an open bug.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That was it! At least it's a relief knowing that it wasn't something I was doing, because I was quite lost, and there actually was a minor version upgrade from 5.7.13 to 5.7.14 that solved the issue. Thank you for the tip!